# How to check whether the device is idle or moving for Android App?

Tags: android, device, accelerometer, hardware-acceleration

- In one of my mobile application, **I wanted to** store real-time latitude and longitude of the user using GPS of Android device.
- **For that**, I am going to use an API to send the value of latitude and longitude of device and will going to call that API every 10 seconds.
- **But, when** the device is in idle mode and not moving anywhere, I don't want to send a request through API to avoid unnecessary load on the server.
- **Is there** any method in Android Library that can detect that the device is moving or not? If the device is in pocket or I put it in the car in my purse, it must check that I am walking or sleeping or the car is moving or not.

I am a novice to Android.

Thanks
JD

Answer (score 3):

Save last sent latitude and longitude in shared prefs and calculate distance between last location and current location , If distance is more then update new location to server .

To calculate distance use this function

```
 private float calculateLocationDifference() {
    float[] dist = new float[1];
    Location.distanceBetween(lastLocation.getLatitude(), lastLocation.getLongitude(), currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude(), dist);
    return dist[0];
}
```

Please do note that getting location continuously will drain the user battery faster .

Comment: That's why I wanted to check whether the device is moving or not instead of using GPS location. If the phone is continuously moving, it should call the API and store the data in database.

Comment: There is no other way to detect if device is moving or not

Comment: The method I said will only save burden from server , not for the user

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using Activity Recognition API in android. There are various activity to identify.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/transitions